# Trying to get a link from a dataframe to extract information

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to get a loop working that will take the link from the data frame created and continue to with more scrapping. What am I doing wrong? Is the source link reading in the loop?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['link'],data=[url.a.get('href') for url in soup.find_all('div',class_="link")])


for i in range(0,33):
    link = df.iloc[i]
    source1 = urllib.request.urlopen(link).read()
    soup1 = bs.BeautifulSoup(source1,'lxml')
    for username in soup1.find_all('div', class_="user-name"):
        print(username.text)
```

Comment: I still do not understand why you are using pd?

Comment: i am using pd to store all the links to a data frame and then reference it

Comment: why don't you use list

Comment: in order to learn how to use pandas

Comment: @Data1234 what is the error stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problems with your code is the way you get the link from dataframe. It should be:

```
link = df.link.iloc[i]
```

instead of

```
link = df.iloc[i]
```

because the latter returns an `object` while `urlopen(link)` expects a `string`. We would be able to make better guess if error message/stacktrace is provided.